# Indexing a nested list

Tags: python, indexing

I am currently writing a python program which involves heavy use of indexing a maze, like structure. I currently have it set up the list as containing separate nested lists each representing one line of the maze, which I index like so Maze[0][1] for the position of the grid maze which is on the first row and second column. Would my program run faster if I converted the maze to a single list while keeping track of how long a row is, and moving through the list accordingly. How much more of a speed boost would I receive if I utilized Maze[(0*row_length)+1] instead of Maze[0][1]?

Comment: Perhaps give an excerpt of the data structure you're talking about.

Comment: My data structure is an index of characters representing either a wall, a empty space, the player, or a movable box. Here is a small example: [['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
          ['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X'],
          ['X', 'X', 'O', ' ', 'X'],
          ['X', '@', ' ', ' ', 'X'],
          ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']]

Comment: If that's the case, I'd be inclined to agree with the given answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother. This is almost certainly not your bottleneck, and it's not worth the headache of managing the indexing calculations and the row length variable.

Timing data:

```
>>> timeit("a[1][2]", setup="a = [[0]*5 for _ in xrange(4)]")
0.09207810811146055
>>> timeit("a[1*5+2]", setup="a = [0]*5*4")
0.06518904043262097
>>> timeit("a[1*row_length+2]", setup="a = [0]*5*4; row_length=5")
0.11411290029380439
```

The flattened list won when the row length was an inlined constant, but it lost when the row length was a global variable. If you try to gain an advantage by flattening your list, you will waste a ton of time managing the indexes, and unless you do it very carefully, it may even run slower. Don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand, by running the following:

```
from timeit import timeit

class slice_list(list):
    def __getitem__(self, iindex):
        return list.__getslice__(self, (iindex * 5), ((iindex + 1) * 5))

nested_list = \
[
    ["X", "X", "X", "X", "X"],
    ["X", " ", " ", " ", "X"],
    ["X", "X", "O", " ", "X"],
    ["X", "@", " ", " ", "X"],
    ["X", "X", "X", "X", "X"]
]

flat_list = \
[
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X",
    "X", " ", " ", " ", "X",
    "X", "X", "O", " ", "X",
    "X", "@", " ", " ", "X",
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"
]

s_list = slice_list(flat_list)

nested_setup_str = \
'''
from __main__ import nested_list

test = nested_list
'''

flat_setup_str = \
'''
from __main__ import flat_list

test = flat_list
'''

slice_setup_str = \
'''
from __main__ import s_list

test = s_list
'''

print "Flat:", timeit("test[1 * 5 + 2]", setup=flat_setup_str)
print "Nested:", timeit("test[1][2]", setup=nested_setup_str)
print "Sliced:", timeit("test[1][2]", setup=slice_setup_str)
```

I got:

```
Flat:   0.1130175887
Nested: 0.182156054306
Sliced: 1.92594956774
```

So whatever gains you get from going to a flat list, it's destroyed by trying to treat it like a nested list (using something similar to slice_list in the above example).

If performance is an issue, perhaps consider a numpy array (although you may have to create a number to symbol mapping).