# More pythonic method of indexing with a list of coordinates

Tags: python, list, coordinates

So I am designing a program which needs to index a nested list, using a stored list of coordinates:

e.g

```
coordinate = [2,1]
```

For a function which returns the element in the nested list, I use

```
return room[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]]
```

My programming instincts tell me that this seems overly long, and there should be a shorter method of doing this especially in Python, but I can't seem to find anything of the sort. Does anyone know if there is a method like this?

Comment: Are you storing coordinates inside a room?

Comment: Given your [prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17758431/282912) are you sure that a list is the best representation of a maze? A dictionary would give you far more flexibility for representing adjacency and such. Put another way, as soon as you've chosen a list of lists, you've locked yourself into a cartesian plane and have to track many coordinate pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the coordinates into more than one variable.

```
i, j = [2, 1]
return room[i][j]
```

or

```
coordinates = [2, 1]
### do stuff with coordinates
i, j = coordinates
return room[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `numpy` module has convenient indexing. It would work well if your `room` is very large.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> room = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> room
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> coords = (2, 1) # it's important this is a tuple
>>> room[coords]
9
```

To convert your `room` variable to a `numpy` array, assuming it is a 2 dimensional nested list, just do

```
>>> room = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> room = np.array(room)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: numpy saves the day, +1

Comment: Why the downvotes? Because the variable is named `room`, it seems most likely that OP has a positional grid in a single room. It would be convenient, and easier, to construct and access this grid as a `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
coordinates[2][1] = "blah"
```

is how you properly index into a nested list

using a tuple is probably a good way to store a static, immutable coordinate

```
myCoord = (2,1)
```

Your way of indexing into your nested `room` array looks right and is a readable option.  I'd have to see more of how you are using it to make a recommendation on what data types to use.

**edit**
In response to your comment, I'd say if this was a function, to accept `x`, and `y` as inputs or if that is not possible do `x,y = myTuple`
so that you could then do this:

```
room[x][y]
```

instead of

```
room[coords[0]][coords[1]]
```

That will make it a bit more readable since that seems to be your concern.  There is NOT a way to natively index a nested list using a tuple

Comment: This is how you index a nested list, but in order to access the nested list I need to use the first and second elements of coordinates, thus using room[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]], with the first index being coordinate[0], and the second coordinate[1]. My question is whether using a variable with two elements you can enter the nested list without needing to separate the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own recursive indexing function:

```
def rec(x, i):
    if i: return rec(x[i[0]], i[1:])
    else: return x
```

Which gives:

```
>>> room = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]
>>> rec(room, (2,1))
[16, 17, 18]
>>> rec(room, [2,1,1])
17
```

Comment: This might be a standard trick in lisp or so, but a recursive function that needs to go 3 level deep to look up a 2D coordinate is not exactly pythonic ...

Comment: True. I guess I overreacted on accessing a LISt, overlooking the 'pythonic' part :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use NumPy:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: a = numpy.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

In [4]: coords = (2, 1)

In [5]: a[coords]
Out[5]: 11
```

If this is not an option, you could subclass list to implement this kind of indexing:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, collections.Iterable):
            return reduce(operator.getitem, index, self)
        return list.__getitem__(self, index)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> a = MyList([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> coords = (2, 1)
>>> a[coords]
11
```

Comment: Numpy is not part of the standard library so it needs to be installed separately. It is good if you are doing number-crunching, but using it for implementing a simple game it is like 'killing a mosquito with a canon'.

Comment: @BasSwinckels: I don't know whether the OP is working on a "simple game", and I don't care.  I give two ways of achieving what is asked for, and let the OP (and future visitors of this question) choose what works for them.  That said, I diasgree that NumPy is overkill for a simple game just because yout have to install it separately.  Would you also argue the PyGame is overkill for a simple game?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that you are using a list as the data structure for information that you want to access in a non-listy way.

The list itself is fine, you might ultimately want to make it an object that has-a list as its storage but presents a more task-oriented interface the the user.

If you aren't ready to tackle a class, this gets you closer to Don't Repeat Yourself:

```
def room_at_coordinate(rooms, coordinate)
    return rooms[coordinate[0]][coordinate[1]]

>>> room_at_coordinate(rooms, coordinate)
'bathroom'
```

This function will slip naturally into an object should you decide to go that route.